# source for Potiphar not believing his wife

Tags: sources-mekorot, parshanut-torah-comment, yosef, parashat-vayeishev

I mentioned to someone a vort I once heard pointing out a difficulty in the story of Potiphar's wife.  Why did Potiphar not have Yosef killed, which would be the expected punishment for attacking the wife of a high-level government minister?

The answer is that Potiphar noticed that his wife had ripped the *back* of Yosef's garment, which would seem to indicate that Yosef was trying to *get away* from the wife, not trying to attack her.  For this reason (and also because he knew Yosef's character) Potiphar did not believe his wife's story.

However Potiphar was not prepared to exonerate Yosef, as that would amount to publicly exposing his wife as a liar, so he had Yosef put in prison instead.

I was asked for a source for this but don't remember any.  What is the source?

Comment: mentioned here without source https://books.google.com/books?id=iVTFWW-STE4C&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=potiphar+wife+back+believe+rip&source=bl&ots=FNEjD5DXJT&sig=_bv4vjkm0D-Orz2Lm_JGdVtHCNM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNpem9mcbJAhXG2B4KHdf4DEQQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=potiphar%20wife%20back%20believe%20rip&f=false

Comment: and here, interestingly enough al-Tabari, Muhammad ibn Jarir (Translated by William Brinner) (1987). The History of al-Tabari Vol. 2: Prophets and Patriarchs. SUNY. pp. 157–158. from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_in_Islam look for footnote 36 in the text

Comment: I also searched online and could find it only mentioned without source, usually by Christian authors

Comment: Most of the references I found were to the Quran.

Comment: I'm almost positive it is brought in The Midrash Says, you can look there for the source. Also, it brings that Potiphar's wife used egg whites to simulate Semen, but they tested it by bringing it close to a fire and it got harder instead of softer.

Comment: Targm Yonatan on gen 39:14-20 has Potiphar's wife attempting to simulate a rape by using eggwhites in place of semen, and Potiphar ultimately throwing Joseph in prison instead of killing him at the advice of priests who investigate the evidence and discover the ruse. There is no mention of the clothing tearing from behind, or of Potiphar not wanting to embarrass his wife though. So this stays a comment!

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65965/how-is-it-that-no-one-spots-potiphars-wifes-lie

Answer (score 1):

Bamidbar Rabba 87 9 [here](http://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.87) has Potiphar telling Yosef he does not believe his wife's story and knows Yosef is innocent. But he was compelled to lock Yosef up so as to stop people from saying that the children of Potiphar were illegitimate.

Comment: Can you take a photo of the text and post it?

Comment: Theres a link for you. Sorry, they only have hebrew for that chapter.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Baby Seal this sourced from a medrash (as per OP comment) where Potiphar is found not believing his wife. While many of the other details are not here, I'm quite sure that portion is not directly from a medrash.

Comment: But the question wants a source for him not believing his wife for the specific reason mentioned. I think the question is too specific, (and that your answer is good), but as it stands, it doesn't answer the question. I will comment above.

Comment: @Baby Seal That's true. But sometimes in our memories we mix actual sources with explanations given by third parties. It could be whoever the OP heard this from wasnt clear when relating various ideas, which part was from a medrash, which from a later source. I'm just providing this source to clarify. If it helps someone somewhere, mah tov umah na'im.

Comment: your answer belongs here! http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65965/how-is-it-that-no-one-spots-potiphars-wifes-lie?lq=1\

Comment: @Baby Seal k thanks. Maybe I'll move it soon. But I still think that if the OP here wants a midrashic source, he is going to have to settle for my offering. Unless the Oznayim LaTorah in Saba's answer has a medrash source, or the OP settles for a non midrashic source. The Shul I will be devening Mincha in has a set. I'll check Bli nedder.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Sorotzkin in Oznayim Latorah Vayeishev 39:12 cites *Moshav Zekeinim* on *Vayigash* and says that Potiphar gave Yosef's cloak (that his wife had grabbed) to the investigating priests. The said that if Yosef had attacked her it would be ripped in front. If it was ripped from behind, he was running away from her and she had grabbed it (meaning he was innocent.

They determined that she had grabbed it from behind, based on the position of the rips (as you state in the question). Rabbi Sorotzkin states that the priests added that Yosef should be transferred to the prison to save her reputation.

I verified the commentary in Oznayim Latorah (39:12) when I went to shul on the first night of Chanukah. I have not found the *Moshav Zekeinim* on Vayigash to put that in as a quote.

I did find a [referece](http://images.shulcloud.com/193/uploads/parsha_questions/5775/vayigash_-_december__2014---parsha_questions.pdf)

> Why did Yosef not take the priests’ land in return for food
>
> Yosef rewarded them for their defending him when  Potifar was going to
>   kill him, by proving that  Yosef had run away from Potifar’s wife
>   (Targum Yonatan)